# Salvar estado de uma CheckBox

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Estou precisando salvar o estado das minhas CheckBox, elas estão dentro de um Spinner, e sempre que eu abro o Spinner ele limpa as CheckBox.

**AdmListagem.java**

```
        final String[] select_qualification = {
                "Todos", "1", "2", "3", "4",
                "5", "6"};
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayList<StateVO> listVOs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < select_qualification.length; i++) {
            StateVO stateVO = new StateVO();
            stateVO.setTitle(select_qualification[i]);
            stateVO.setSelected(false);
            listVOs.add(stateVO);
        }
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(AdmListagem.this, 0,
                listVOs);
        spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**spinner_item2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_border" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StateVO>  {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<StateVO> listState;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private boolean isFromView = false;
    String[] values;
    Boolean[] checkedStatus;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<StateVO> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listState = (ArrayList<StateVO>) objects;
        this.myAdapter = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView,
                              ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTextView.setText(listState.get(position).getTitle());

        // To check weather checked event fire from getview() or user input
        isFromView = true;
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());
        isFromView = false;

        if ((position == 0)) {
            holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                String t = String.valueOf(getPosition);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    }
}
```

**StateVO.java**

```
public class StateVO {
    private String title;
    private boolean selected;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Ao executar a aplicação e no Spinner escolher os itens, e clicar na tela, e abrir o Spinner novamente ele está sem nenhuma marcação nas CheckBox

Comment: Use variáveis estaticas para isso ou sharedpreferences, tambem pode te ajudar a salvar o valor

Comment: @Matheus Conseguiria me dar uma ajuda me mostrando como ficaria ?

Comment: Então... é que é um processo um pouco trabalhoso, no seu caso você terá que acessar os filhos do seu spinner, e ver qual filho é o checkBox, depois quando for clicado no botão para checar, salvar em uma variavel ambiente que seria as Sharedpreferences...

Comment: @Matheus, Ah sim, então vou tentar utilizar isto que você falou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponho que a razão do campo `selected` da classe StateVO seja para isso mesmo.

No *adapter* use-o para guardar e recuperar o estado do CheckBox.

A parte de recuperar já você fez. Falta a parte de guardar, que deve ser feita no `onCheckedChanged()`

```
public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {

    ...
    ...
    // To check weather checked event fire from getview() or user input
    isFromView = true;
    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());
    isFromView = false;

    //holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isFromView)return;

            //int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            String t = String.valueOf(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Guarda o estado do CheckBox
            listState.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

**Notas:**

- Não há necessidade de guardar a posição do item na `tag`do CheckBox.
  Desde que `position`seja declarado como final é possível usá-lo dentro do método `onCheckedChanged()`.
- Usei a *flag* `isFromView` para que o método `onCheckedChanged()` retorne de imediato de forma a que o Toast seja apresentado apenas quando o usuário clicar no CheckBox.
- Se não quiser fazer uso da *flag* e continuar a usar a `tag`, para que seja obtida a posição correcta no método `onCheckedChanged()`, esta deve receber o valor da posição antes da linha   `holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());`

Comment: Tentei fazer assim, porem as vezes ele não salva e quando salva ele embaralha as checkbox que estão selecionadas, por exemplo marcando as duas ultimas, quando eu abro ta a 2 e a 3.

Comment: Não vejo porquê. Ele também troca o texto?

Comment: Não, ele não troca a posição dos textos, eu havia tentado antes porém esqueci de mencionar na pergunta.

Comment: Eu faço sempre assim e funciona. A única diferença é que não uso a `tag` para guardar a posição, uso `position` directamente. No entanto não vejo que isso seja problema.

Comment: Nossa estranho então, devo ter feito algo errado, porém onde não sei

Comment: Julgo que descobri o problema: ao fazer `holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());`antes de "setar" a tag a posição obtida por `getTag()` no `onCheckedChanged()` ´obtida uma posição errada. 3 formas de resolver: 1 - usar a flag `isFromView`; 2 - "setar a `tag` antes; 3 - usar `position` em vez de `getTag()`. Vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: Conseguiria editar a pergunta me mostrando como alterar aqui ? Se sim muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu já inclui na resposta as alterações que deve fazer no código. A pergunta não deve ser editada senão as respostas ficam sem sentido.

Comment: Eu acabei errando no que falei deveria ter falado "Editar sua resposta"

Comment: Consegue entender as alterações que fiz? Apenas comentei algumas linhas, usei `position`em vez de `getPosition`, adicionei `if(isFromView)return;` e  `listState.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);`

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi sim as alterações me ajudou muito e valeu pela atenção cara